# Start scrolling horizontal UIScrollView in UITableView only if horizontal scroll is at least 2 times vertical scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and each of its cells contains a `UIScrollView` that can scroll only horizontally.

I would like to trigger the horizontal scroll of the `UITableViewCell` only if for example the velocity on x is at least 2 times faster than the velocity on y. If it's not the case, then the `UITableView` can normally scroll vertically.

So far I have tried to subclass my `UITableView` and override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`. But it didn't work as I realised the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` of my horizontal `UIScrollView` (the one of top of each cell) was called first.

So I decided to override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` on my horizontal `UIScrollView`:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let velocity = (gestureRecognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).velocityInView(tableView)

        return fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y) * 2
    }

    return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

The problem then is that is I return `false` then the UITableView doesn't scroll (`gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` is not even called).

How can I fix this? Why does it behave like this?

Comment: have you tried setting 'delaysContentTouches' on the tabelview to false ?

Comment: Yes I tried, it doesn't fix it.

Comment: add swipe gesture instead of PanGesture

Comment: No, I want to be able to do a pan as well as a swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `canCancelContentTouches` on your ScrollView to false?

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the gesture of the `UIScrollView` and I would  override the gesture recognizer of the table. 
Once the pan starts,you keep a reference to the "tapped" cell, and according to the value of your condition you can programmatically/manually scroll the table or the `UIScrollView`  inside the cell. `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` has different methods to set the (scroll) content offset.

Comment: If I disable the gesture on the UIScrollView, then I cannot pan horizontally as the horizontal `contentSize` of the `tableView` is about the same width than the phone. Then doing it programmatically would make me lose the `UIScrollView` behaviour regarding the deceleration and I want to keep it.